# understanding merge sort in ML

Tags: merge, functional-programming, sml, mergesort

I have an assignment to translate the following ML code into Java, but I cannot tell what it is doing.  What are the 'halve' and 'merge' functions doing here?

```
fun halve nil = (nil, nil)
|   halve [a] = ([a], nil)
|   halve (a :: b :: cs) =
      let
        val (x, y) = halve cs
      in
        (a :: x, b :: y)
      end;

fun merge (nil, ys) = ys
|   merge (xs, nil) = xs
|   merge (x :: xs, y :: ys) =
      if (x > y) then x :: merge(xs, y :: ys)
      else y :: merge(x :: xs, ys);

fun mergeSort nil = nil
|   mergeSort [a] = [a]
|   mergeSort theList =
      let
        val (x, y) = halve theList
      in
        print("xList: "^printList(x));
        print("yList: "^printList(y));
        merge(mergeSort x, mergeSort y)
      end;
```

Comment: `halve` and `merge` are pretty much the basis of the merge sort algorithm. It makes sense to look at the algorithm rather than the code, since that is what is common between SML and Java implementations.

Answer (score 1):

`halve` splits a list in two by adding its elements alternatingly to two lists (this saves you from having to calculate the length first and *then* splitting it, which would require 1.5 traversals of the list instead of just one).

`merge` merges two lists in decreasing order.

`mergeSort` splits a list in two, sorts the two halves, then merges the sorted sublists.